# 'else if' logical statements in gnuplot

Tags: if-statement, logic, gnuplot

The new gnuplot (5.x) has new syntax for logic, but I cannot get the 'else if' statement to work. For example:

```
if(flag==1){
plot sin(x)
}
else{
plot cos(x)
}
```

does work, but:

```
if(flag==1){
plot sin(x)
}
else if(flag==2){
plot cos(x)
}
else if(flag==3){
plot tan(x)
}
```

does not. I have tried many combinations of {} and placement of 'if' and 'else' to no avail. Does anyone know how to correctly implement 'else if' in gnuplot 5.x?

The gnuplot guide (http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/if.html) has no examples of the new logic syntax using 'else if' but does have examples using the old syntax, but I would rather avoid the old.

Comment: You can avoid using `else` in your second example and get what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on a brief inspection of the source code of `command.c` in the latest version of Gnuplot, I would say that this feature is not supported. To be more specific, the relevant part can be found on line `1163` (see below). The parser first makes sure that the `if` is followed by a condition enclosed in parentheses. If the following token is a `{`, it activates the new syntax, isolates the entire if block enclosed in a pair of matching `{}` and optionally looks for an `else` which is however permitted to be followed also only with a `{}`-enclosed clause. Because of this, a simple script such as:

```
if(flag == 1){
    print 1;
}else if(flag == 2){
    print 2;
}
```

indeed produces the error message `expected {else-clause}`. One workaround would be to nest the if statements as:

```
if(flag == 1){

}else{
    if(flag == 2){

    }else{
        if(flag == 3){

        }
    }
}
```

which is admittedly slightly more verbose...

```
void
if_command()
{
    double exprval;
    int end_token;

    if (!equals(++c_token, "("))    /* no expression */
    int_error(c_token, "expecting (expression)");
    exprval = real_expression();

    /*
     * EAM May 2011
     * New if {...} else {...} syntax can span multiple lines.
     * Isolate the active clause and execute it recursively.
     */
    if (equals(c_token,"{")) {
    /* Identify start and end position of the clause substring */
    char *clause = NULL;
    int if_start, if_end, else_start=0, else_end=0;
    int clause_start, clause_end;

    c_token = find_clause(&if_start, &if_end);

    if (equals(c_token,"else")) {
        if (!equals(++c_token,"{"))
        int_error(c_token,"expected {else-clause}");
        c_token = find_clause(&else_start, &else_end);
    }
    end_token = c_token;

    if (exprval != 0) {
        clause_start = if_start;
        clause_end = if_end;
        if_condition = TRUE;
    } else {
        clause_start = else_start;
        clause_end = else_end;
        if_condition = FALSE;
    }
    if_open_for_else = (else_start) ? FALSE : TRUE;

    if (if_condition || else_start != 0) {
        clause = new_clause(clause_start, clause_end);
        begin_clause();
        do_string_and_free(clause);
        end_clause();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. What a shame that support for 'else if' has been dropped. I guess your workaround is the best that can be done in such circumstances.